Visualize multiple variables on one shapefile, QGIS
My goal is to visualize three variables on one shapefile layer in QGIS. I am trying to:

Determine the colour of each line in a shapefile based on one column/set of values in the attribute table.
Determine the width of each line based on another column in the table.
Determine if a line is solid or dashed based on another true/false value in the attribute table.

All at once!
I am able to do these things individually, but it is essential that I represent them simultaneously.
Is there a way to set the width and line type using an expression that incorporates attribute values?

Have you read up on data-driven/-defined override?

Before trying to do three at once, what did you try and where did you get stuck trying to do just two of them at once?
